# Validating paypal transaction ID with PHP?

Tags: php, validation, paypal, paypal-ipn

I used paypal IPN before to add the payments to a database, but now what I want to do is to have a textbox where I input **only** a paypal transaction ID, submit the form and know if the transaction ID is from a valid payment or not.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Un-accept So I can Delete this answer] - No longer supporting link to download**

Please refer to the SDK http://www.paypalobjects.com/IntegrationCenter/ic_sdk.html

Comment: -1 | You should make sure that the linked file stays accessible, otherwise you should edit your answer.